# Discord.py how can I get information to a youtube video

Tags: discord.py

I want to get information to a youtube video ... If somebody send the bot !yt_video 
I want that a message came were stand the information

But I don't know how can I make, that the bot can access the youtube information

Comment: Does this help? [How to get a YouTube video's information with YouTube Data API by Python?](https://jingwen-z.github.io/how-to-get-a-youtube-video-information-with-youtube-data-api-by-python/)

Answer (score 0):

**YouTube API**

You can use the YouTube API with Python to grab information.

YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/
Most child company's to Google have a API. Just have a look at Google's API's.